# Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause(). on iframe load

Tags: video, iframe

I am adding a vimeo Iframe on click into a popup and I get the: 
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause(). error...

After some research I understand that this is a chrome bug and there are some ways to fix this via js , but I am not sure how to do that if my video is inside an Iframe.. how can I manipulate it when it is in Iframe?

Comment: Looks like it is issue with Viemo itself: Some info here https://vimeo.com/forums/api/topic:289672